# MYSQL query INNER JOIN two table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables `CLASSES`, `CHILD_CLASSES`, and `STUDENTS`.

`CLASSES` looks like this (its self referencing):

```
CLASS_ID | CLASS_PARENT |
-------------------------
    1    |      ---
    2    |       1 
    3    |       2
```

`CHILD_CLASSES` looks like this:

```
CC_ID | PARENT_CLASS_ID | CHILD_CLASS_ID
----------------------------------------
  1   |       1         |     2    
  2   |       1         |     3
  3   |       2         |     3
```

`STUDENTS` looks like this

```
 STU_ID | CLASS_ID | STU_NAME
 ----------------------------
    1   |     1    |     A
    2   |     1    |     B
    3   |     2    |     C
```

Basically the `CLASSES` table is self referencing but each CLASS can also have children associated with that class. So CLASS 1 has children 2 and 3 and Class 2 has children of just 3.

So a many students can have the same class id. The students are also allowed to see all information that is a child of the class_id that is associated with them so any student with class ID of 1 can see classes 1,  2 and 3 but a student with a class idea of 2 can only see classes with ID 2 and 3. I am trying to find a query to count the number of users of a particular class that have access. so if I was looking at class_id of 1 the query would return 3 because it has two children in the CHILD_CLASSES table and then itself in the classes table. I cant seem to get this to work though, I always come up short because due to trying to count the 1 user in the CLASSES table.

the query I am using so far is this

```
SELECT COUNT(class_id) as TOTAL 
  FROM students 
 WHERE class_id IN (SELECT class_id 
                      FROM child_classes 
                     WHERE parent_class_id = 1);
```

Comment: Could you post the query you are using?

Comment: so my query will only return 2 because it is only finding the two classes in the CHILD_CLASSES table where the class_id is the same. I need to somehow add to the total the result of SELECT COUNT(class_id) FROM classes where class_id = 1;

Comment: IF you were using Pg you could do a recursive query where classes could be N-level deep. It would also be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `child_classes` contains the same data as `classes`, so the following should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM students
WHERE class_id = 1
   OR class_id IN ( SELECT child_class_id
                    FROM child_classes
                    WHERE parent_class_id = 1
                  )
```

It returns the count of all `students` which have `class_id = 1` or are in a class which has `parent_class_id = 1`.

Comment: Thank you this works, I knew I was close. yes it does contain the same data and there is a reason for that but anyway this is great thank you